# How do I prevent the line from not breaking in a header of a page?(html)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am rendering a value from the database which seems fine and accurate when i console.log it. I use it on the header's text-content and it results with no errors, but the original text has line breakers in it when the user presses enter, and the only displayed has none!I checked again the value of the header with console.log and this is what came out:

[image]

dont mind the errors, they are normal and supposed to happen and unrelated, the third console.log is the textContent of the header printed, it clearly has line breaks, but here is a photo of the header:

[image]

it seems that the header eliminated the line breaks? how do I stop it from doing it?

Thanks!

Comment: Mind if you send us your HTML code?

Comment: Maybe try to use regex to remove the line breaks?

Comment: You can also just use ````white-space: pre-line```` CSS attribute on the Tag containing your line breaks.